# How to Enter Unique Data In to Core Data Value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

i am Newbie in iOS Development. i want to Show only Single Value in Core Data Table for Duplicate Data Array. i know that this question are asked many times i search fro it but i not get the Solution. Please Help me for that.

i create an app that Contain One View in One View i make an HMSegmentedControll and in HMSegmentedControll i add `10` Segmented Controls and each Segmented Controls Contain UITableView i want to Make When User Select any UITableViewCell then its Data also Stored in Core Data, it is Working fine but Always it Add Same data i want to Stop Duplication of this same Data Array. Please Give me Solution For this

Here my Code for UITableViewCell Selection Method.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
if (self.bookMark)
{
    [self.bookMark setValue:cell.headLabel.text forKey:@"title"];
    [self.bookMark setValue:cell.categoryLabel.text forKey:@"category"];
    [self.bookMark setValue:cell.timeLabel.text forKey:@"post_date"];
    [self.bookMark setValue:image forKey:@"imagelink"];
    [self.bookMark setValue:post_id forKey:@"post_id"];
    [self.bookMark setValue:self.shortDiscription forKey:@"shortdescription"];
}
else
{
     newBookMark = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"BookMark" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newBookMark setValue:cell.headLabel.text forKey:@"title"];
    [newBookMark setValue:cell.categoryLabel.text forKey:@"category"];
    [newBookMark setValue:cell.timeLabel.text forKey:@"post_date"];
    [newBookMark setValue:image forKey:@"imagelink"];
    [newBookMark setValue:post_id forKey:@"post_id"];
    [newBookMark setValue:self.shortDiscription forKey:@"shortdescription"];
}
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
}
```

And Here `self.bookMark` and `newBookMark` both are `NSManagedObject`.

And i Code for Fetch a Request as

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:@"BookMark" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
NSError *error;
self.allreadArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

And i set Here Dictionary to fetch data like as

```
NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entity propertiesByName];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"post_id"]]];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"title"]]];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"shortdescription"]]];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"post_date"]]];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"category"]]];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"imagelink"]]];
```

and here i show Fetch Data in tableview cell as

```
-(CustumCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
CustumCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustumCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
[cell.spinner startAnimating];
[cell.headLabel setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
cell.viewLabel.hidden=TRUE;
NSManagedObject *device = [self.allreadArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSString  *image=[device valueForKey:@"imagelink"];
if([image isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    [cell.cellImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[image stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Setting.png"] options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
     {
         [cell.spinner stopAnimating];
         cell.spinner.hidesWhenStopped=YES;
     }];
}
cell.headLabel.text=[device valueForKey:@"title"];
cell.categoryLabel.text=[device valueForKey:@"category"];
cell.timeLabel.text=[device valueForKey:@"post_date"];
return cell;
}
```

then it is Always Fetch @"imagelink" data i want to Fetch All Data Please Give me Solution for that 
thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where are you getting `cell`? You need to figure out which cell was tapped in your code.

Comment: To answer the final part of your question, `setPropertiesToFetch` is not cumulative: each time you call, it clears the previous list.  You should combine all those objects into a single array: `[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[[entityProperties objectForKey:@"post_id"],[entityProperties objectForKey:@"title"],[entityProperties objectForKey:@"shortdescription"],[entityProperties objectForKey:@"post_date"],[entityProperties objectForKey:@"category"],[entityProperties objectForKey:@"imagelink"]]];`.

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh My TableView Contain More Data When User Select Any Cell and Read It's Contain Then i want to store that cell contain in Another view that display already read cell data. so i use core data to tableview cell select method.

Comment: @pbasdf when i write as to fetch all data then it give me result as same but not only give one cell for same data.and here i want to fetch value like as `[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"Key"]]` Because it Give me Only One Value for all duplicate array value.

Comment: @pbasdf when i write as `NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"title"]];` then i got only Distinct value for my array `title` key i want distance key for all my key like as `post_id`,`posttitle`,`date` etc. how i get it please give me solution for it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to achieve.  Could you explain where in your code the fetch is undertaken, and why?  Also provide some more of your table view code (e.g. `cellForRowAtIndexPath`).  That might help me understand.  Thanks.

Comment: @pbasdf here i edit my code please give me Solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of places where your problem could lie.  I'll list them all, in the hope that one of them is of some help:

**First**, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you have:

```
NSManagedObject *device = [self.allreadArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

Hence you are using the `section` number to determine which `device` you use to populate the cell.  This will be the same `device` for every cell in the section.  It may be that is deliberate (you might want several sections with a single cell in each, rather than one section).  But you might instead mean to use the `row` number to determine which `device` to use, so that every row is different.  If so, replace the above line with:

```
NSManagedObject *device = [self.allreadArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**Secondly**, in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, you save the attribute values either to `self.bookMark` (if it exists) or to a newly created `Bookmark` object.  But you do not set `self.bookMark` anywhere.  Hence, every time you select a row, you create a new object.  If you actually want `self.bookMark` to refer to that newly created bookmark object, then add:

```
self.bookMark = newBookMark;
```

to the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, immediately after you create `newBookMark`.  Hence the next time you select a row, `self.bookMark` will exist and you will save the new values to it, rather than creating another (duplicate) object.

**Thirdly**, your fetch is using `setReturnsDistinctResults`.  It is unusual to use this, though it might be what you need.  But are you using that option just to overcome the problem of having duplicate objects in your database?  To use an example, suppose you have four objects with the following attributes:

```
title    post_id    category    imageLink
Red      0001       Primary     pic1.jpg
Blue     0002       Primary     pic2.jpg
Green    0003       Secondary   pic1.jpg
Red      0004       Secondary   pic2.jpg
```

If you use `setReturnsDistinctResults` with `setPropertiesToFetch` set to `imageLink`, then the results will include only two items:

```
imageLink
pic1.jpg
pic2.jpg
```

With `setPropertiesToFetch` set to both `imageLink` and `category`, then your results will include four items:

```
category    imageLink
Primary     pic1.jpg
Primary     pic2.jpg
Secondary   pic1.jpg
Secondary   pic2.jpg
```

If you actually want to know the distinct values for each attribute, then you must run the fetch several times, and change the `propertiesToFetch` each time:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entity propertiesByName];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"post_id"]]];
self.postIdArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"title"]]];
self.titleArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
etc, etc.
```

That will result in two arrays, postIdArray having four items:

```
post_id
0001
0002
0003
0004
```

and titleArray having three items:

```
title
Red
Blue
Green
```

Which of these best describes what you want to obtain in your fetch?

Sorry for a long answer.  Let me know if any of this is helpful or irrelevant, and I will add to or amend the answer accordingly.